# From Kubernetes CRD to Go import

Tags: go, kubernetes, visual-studio-code

Imagine you want to get kind/struct called `KubeadmControlPlane` from the kubernetes API server.

This means you need to import the related struct into your code.

A matching import statement for `KubeadmControlPlane` would be:

> kubeadm "sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/controlplane/kubeadm/api/v1beta1"

Up to now I need to much time to find a matching import statement.

I use vscode.

How do you get from the CRD kind to an import statement?

Comment: Are the names of the all CRD kinds and their related structs, same ?

Comment: @BrokenArmor please elaborate your question. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, a `go get sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api@v1.4.2` (done in the folder where your `go.mod` is) should be enough to:

- update your `go.mod`,
- add the library in your `$GOPATH` and
- enable VSCode auto-import to work.

That means, when you start typing the name of a struct, like `KubeadmControlPlane`, the [VSCode Go extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go) should suggest an auto-import if it can find a matching package in your `GOPATH` or in your project's vendor directory.

---

If not, the manual process would be:

1. **Identify the API Group and Version of the CRD:** This information is usually found in the `apiVersion` field of the CRD YAML file. For example, the `KubeadmControlPlane` is part of the `controlplane.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1beta1` API group and version.
2. **Find the Go Package for the API Group:** You need to find the corresponding Go package for this API group.
   In the case of the `KubeadmControlPlane`, it is part of the `sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api` project and the specific package path is `sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/controlplane/kubeadm/api/v1beta1`.
   A [search in `pkg.go.dev`](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=KubeadmControlPlane) works too, pending an official API to lookup packages ([issue 36785](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36785)).
3. **Identify the Go Struct for the CRD:** The Go struct is usually named similarly to the Kind of the CRD. In this case, it is `KubeadmControlPlane`.
4. **Create the Go Import Statement:** Once you have the package path and struct name, you can create the Go import statement. For example:

```golang
import (
    kubeadm "sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/controlplane/kubeadm/api/v1beta1"
)
```